# Saving to .png from an array gives glitchy results

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Not a big question,
This is the code:

```
def rgb_to_png(rgb, path):
    rgbarray = np.array([np.array([x for x in i]) for i in rgb])
    rgbimage = PIL.Image.fromarray(rgbarray, "RGB")
    
    rgbimage.save(path+"\sample.png", "PNG", quality=100)
```

This is what it's supposed to look like:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAL4j.png)

And this is what the code outputs:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woYvR.png)

It seems that it's saving each rgb value as a single pixel or something similar, but I don't get what's wrong in the code. What is happening in there?

(Note: Both pictures resolution is 128 by 128)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the type of your Numpy arrays as you create them, else they will not be unsigned 8-bit like PIL expects:

```
rgbarray = np.array(..., np.uint8)
```

You can check yours with:

```
print(rgbarray.dtype)
```

---

Also, the last 2 parameters of your `Image.save()` are superfluous.